# Divs not aligning right in IE or FF using display: table and display: inline-block

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, firefox

I have a number of sections running down my site which differ in height but are all 100% width, each section has sub-sections which work the same way and are set to display: table and then have have 2 columns (sometimes 3 and sometimes 1), the columns are display: inline-block and it all works fine in chrome but in ie and ff the columns are all displayed one under the other.

Here is an example of just one:

HTML

```
<div id="features">

    <div class="container">
        <h3>Touch Tomorrow <strong class="blue">Now</strong></h3>
        <div class="column">
            <img src="images/zimx-swipe-10-front-2.png" class="image image-padding" />
        </div>
        <div class="column">
        <div class="spacer"></div>
            <div class="info" id="overview">
                <b4><p>The all new zimx Swipe 10 with</p>
                    <ul>
                        <li>RK3188 chip</li>
                        <li>10.1" LCD screen</li>
                        <li>2GB DDR3 RAM</li>
                        <li>Super fast wireless</li>
                        <li>Over one million apps</li>
                        <li>Android KitKat operating system</li>
                    </ul>
                    <p class="2">Packed into one of the thinnest cases around</p>
                </b4>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <hr class="grey" />
```

CSS

```
#features {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    width: 100%;
}

#features .container {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}

#features .container .column {
    width: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

And here is a link to the site with the issue:
http://zimx.ukbigbuy.com/

[image: Here is a comparison of the site in ie and chrome]

Comment: I opened this in firefox and IE, they all look the same to me.

Comment: That's weird, I have ie 11 installed... have you tired it in chrome?

Comment: You're not crazy, I'm seeing it stack too. A quick fix would be to reduce the widths to 49%, or look into box-sizing: border-box. I think the issue is the padding inside of the columns.

Comment: Thank you, setting the width to 49% worked perfectly, I will look into box-sizing too.

Answer (score 0):

Ahh. So if your elements are displayed inline-block - as your columns are - AND there is a line break between the end of the first inline-block element and the next inline-block element then a space is added between them [~4px]. The fix for this is either to make sure the html has no line breaks between these elements or to use comments between the elements.

Method one:

```
<div class="column">
  <!-- Other Content -->
</div><div class="column">
  <!-- Other Content -->
</div>
```

Method two:

```
<div class="column">
  <!-- Other Content -->
</div><!--
--><div class="column">
  <!-- Other Content -->
</div>
```

Or you can rewrite your css to use floats instead.

Edit: For completeness, there are few ways to deal with this rogue space issue. They are detailed in the link below - but the above two methods will work fine.
http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Comment: If you have a wrapper div around the inline-blocks, you can just set font-size:0 on that to fix it. You'll then need to reset the font size for the divs within.

Comment: Yeah thats one of the other methods mentioned in the css-tricks article - the comment method is my preferred but each to their own :)